# .Net Inline Schema/XML Programmatic Generation for Excel

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, excel, xsd

I have a set of data rendered using ASP.Net (VB.Net) to a web page. I now want to export that data to XML. I have created some code to generate a schema, however, I don't know what to do next. I want to have the schema be in-line with the XML data, and I would like the compiler to check to make sure that the data I'm entering for the XML content validates against the included schema. Anyone know of a way to do this? The idea is for me to be able to open the resultant file in Excel with fields of the correct type.

I've build XML documents before, and this is my first schema document I've created programmatically. However, I've never worked with inline schema's, much less used them to strongly-type the XML being added to the document.

I've read over the following, which were quite helpful, but neither of which addressed the issue I mention above:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/XML/Generating-XML-Schema-Dynamically-Using-VBNET-2005-Essentials/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/06/05/inline-an-xml-schema-into-your-xml-document.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "... I would like the compiler to check to make sure that the data I'm entering for the XML content validates against the included schema."

The compiler never checks that. If you want to validate your XML Document against a schema programmatically, you should probably use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx.

But for inlining the schema with your document, you sort of answered your own question. The second link in your question, to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/06/05/inline-an-xml-schema-into-your-xml-document.aspx, is exactly what you are trying to do.

You can think of an inline XML Schema as a document-within-a-document. Well, using Kirk's example, the outermost document is more of a container which uses the undefined namespace (no schema). His example uses a document root of "DerekDoc" that belongs to the undefined namespace. You can name yours whatever you want.

Inside that root are essentially *two documents*. One is the inline XML Schema. You would just add it as a child element of the root. The other is the XML document that you intended to conform to the XML Schema. You will need to use the `xmlns` attribute to set this element to the namespace defined by your XML Schema (the target namespace of the schema).

It *might* work (I haven't tried it) to set the root element to the target namespace of the schema, but it might be harder for clients to validate the document since it's a forward reference.

Comment: So your saying that I should generate the document with an inline schema and then read it back to make sure it validates? Also, every combination of this that I've tried doesn't open in Excel correctly; so I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: If it's just opening it in Excel, did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948799/generate-an-excel-xml-document-in-asp-net-mvc-web-site

Comment: I think you might be blurring the lines a little. Do you need to validate the XML document that you generate? If so, you probably won't be validating the XML Schema document that you embedded into that XML document. In fact, I'm not entirely sure why you are generating the schema to begin with. XML Schemas are usually used to inform *other people* how to construct a valid XML document.

Comment: What I'm looking to generate is an XML file that can be opened in Excel or that can be validated by an XML processing program. I would prefer to not use an Excel specific format, especially since I know that Excel can open XML file. However, I can't figure out how to get Excel to open an XML file with an embedded schema.

Comment: Another thing is that I now understand that I should just include the schema as the first element in my XML document, and that I then need to read it back to myself to make sure it is valid, however, since I'm processing everything as a stream, I'm not sure how to do that, but I can probably figure this one out.